# how to install Mac OS X on your Windows PC using PearPC?

Tags: windows, macos, installation, emulation

how to install Mac OS X on your Windows PC using PearPC? Anyone have achieve this before?

Comment: superduperuser!

Comment: Looks like the last release was a *long* time ago, and only tested on Mac OS X v10.3. Even this had some compatibility problems. What version of OS X are you trying to run?

Comment: Current version. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay, @Ralph. (Cleaned up my comments.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PearPC is a PowerPC emulator. Apple switched their Mac hardware to Intel/x86 architecture in 2006, the latest Mac OS X release for PowerPC is 10.4 or 10.5.

As you tagged your question *iphone* I assume you want to develop software for it. There's no way to do this using PearPC.

Use a virtualization software, or install directly on the hardware. There are enough related guides on the web and questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071990/can-i-develop-for-iphone-using-pear-pc-or-similiar-besides-vmware)